# Does GCM requires Internet Connection?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Im using GCM to get Notifications for my Android App.
When registering at GCM you have to call:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String registrationID = "";
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcmObject = null;

    try {
        gcmObject = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this.context);
        registrationID = gcmObject.register(Globals.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        registrationID = null;
    }

    return registrationID;
}
```

Is it neccessary to have connection to the internet for that call?
Im asking because i have problems in my intranet where i test my 
application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do need internet because there is a call to register your device so you can get your GCM token

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it requires internet connection. The registration process (the call to `gcmObject.register`) sends a request to the GCM server, so you must have a connection.